# error using list.append() when print works fine

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a simple web scraper that will send me an e-mail about deals posted on a website's page.  I am using beautifulsoup in order to scrape the info into a list called "list".  I can get the output to look they way I want it using a print command, but when I try to use the same loops to append the strings into a list I get the following error

```
> ----- Post with most thanks ------ Traceback (most recent call last):
> ----- Trending Hot Deals ------   File "C:/Users/Geoff/PycharmProjects/web_scraping/Historian_file.py", line
> 45, in <module>
> ----- Popular Threads ------
>     print "\n".join(msg)
> ----- New Posts ------ TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found
> 
> Process finished with exit code 1
```

here is the code, the commented out parts don't work, the print commands do.

```
def title(number):
    if number == 1:
        print "----- Post with most thanks ------"
    elif number == 2:
        print "----- Trending Hot Deals ------"
    elif number == 3:
        print "----- Popular Threads ------"
    else:
        print "----- New Posts ------"
msg = []
x = 1
for i in list:
    print title(x)
    #msg.append(title(x))
    x = x+1
    for j in i:
        l = j.encode_contents()
        print l
        #msg.append(l)

#print "\n".join(msg)
```

I appreciate any help on this.

Thanks

Comment: don't use list as a variable name

Answer (score 0):

Change `print` statement on `return` in the `title` function.

```
def title(number):
    if number == 1:
      return "----- Post with most thanks ------"
    elif number == 2:
      return "----- Trending Hot Deals ------"
    elif number == 3:
      return "----- Popular Threads ------"
    else:
      return "----- New Posts ------"
```

Remember that every function without `return` statement always returns `None`.

Comment: Yes, you are adding the result of `title(x)` to your list. `title()` doesn't return anything, so it returns `None`. Therefore some of the items in your list are `None`. `str.join()` requires all the items to be strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your `title` function doesn't return anything, so when you try to append the result of calling the function, you're not actually appending the result from `title`. Instead, you are appending `None`. To fix this, you need to return them, instead of simply printing them.

Comment: This isn't actually true, `append` works just fine, it appends `None` to the list.  It's actually the `.join()` call that is the problem.

Comment: Right. But clearly he expects that `msg` will contain the message determined by the `title` function. And `msg` does not contain the message because he is not returning it.

Comment: I suppose you're technically right. It works, just not as he wanted or expected it to.

Answer (score 0):

Moved to an answer, because people are shorting you on valid information.

1. Yes you need to `return` data from the function, rather than `print`ing it.  So **change `print` to `return`, and you will be set** (as long as you return strings, or sanitize your data)
2. This is a good lesson on debugging code.  Your stack trace says the issue, but your title ignores it as do some of the others.  `.join()` expects string types, so that is where this is causing you issue.

To debug strange issues, you will want to pay more attention to the stacktrace, which was a little cluttered by the `prints` (don't worry - all of us have ignored this data before).

`None` is a valid type that can be in a list.  As a result, calling `mylist.append(Foo())` when `Foo` returns nothing, appends `None` to your list.  It's completely valid.

Your actual issue, however, is when you try to call `.join(ListWithNotStringsInIt)`.  Read that as:  I gave `.join()` list of items, at least one of them was not a string, nor could it be implicitly cast to a string (`str()`).

How should you solve that to avoid issues in the future? **Sanitize your data**.

List comprehension is a pretty good way to do this, though - it should be completely unnecessary if you are handling your data responsibly:

```
'\n'.join([str(x) for x in my_list])
```

Python expects that you as a programmer are wise about how you can use it.  As a result, you get lots of rope to hang yourself with (such as seeing errors like this).

List comprehension should not be required here, and if you are responsible at using your list correctly, it is *completely unnecessary*.  But it's a way to check what you are getting, especially when there are exceptions thrown and you're debugging the issue.